# How to make items in QListWidget multiline?

Tags: qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

There is `QListWidget`. If I add an item with the text like "Line1\nLine2" I get an item containing a one string.
How can I make this item containing two strings?

Comment: did you try `\n\r`

Comment: @MohammadKanan did not help

Comment: How you add the item? where is your code?

Comment: I added an item to the QListWidget in the following way: `some_list_widget.addItem(QString("Line1\nLine2"));` 
and I get what you want: https://imgur.com/a/TFv5a , You could give more detail.

Comment: @eyllanesc Wow. Same result. Why if add the item using QtDesigner I don't get the same result?

Comment: @Ufx 
Did my solution work?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the editor adds one more backslash as the following image shows:

[image]

The solution is simple, you must edit the text in Object Inspector and add it there directly as I show below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add two lines to `QListWidget` in two way:

First:

```
 listWidget->addItem(tr("Line1\nLine2"));
```

or

```
new QListWidgetItem(tr("Line4\nLine5"), listWidget);
```

and that should work as per common testing.

Second, and the better way is to add multiple items using `addItems()` with `QStringList`

```
QStringList items;
items << "Line1";
items << "Line2";
listWidget->addItems(items);
```